# "Secret" Documentation Privileges on sites other than SO

Tags: bug, privileges, help-center, documentation

I was searching the Help Center and I found something strange:

> Privilege: documentation votes - Vote on documentation content

This wouldn't be strange if I was on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-voting), since they actually have "documentation content". However, I was on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/docs-voting), which doesn't have Documentation (unless it's a secret). It is not listed on the ["full" list of privileges](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

This happens across the network. You can see the same thing happen on [this very site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/docs-voting). Same story for [documentation comments - Comment on proposed changes and topic requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/docs-commenting) and [documentation review - Approve and reject proposed changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/docs-reviewing).

Comment: Well, MSE has the master copy of help center pages, so that's probably [tag:status-bydesign]. The rest is more questionable.

Comment: Also, I noticed that on documentation privileges on sites where I have enough reputation to earn the privilege, [there is a full progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEUnn.png) whereas for real privileges [it says "You earned this privilege"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN5J7.png) (the linked screenshots are from Meta Stack Exchange where I have 929 reputation at the moment I took them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not my doing, but this has been resolved with the removal of Documentation privileges from all sites (since Documentation itself is no more).

You can see this by following the links in the question: they all lead to the main list of privileges. Additionally they do not turn up in searches.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is due to the wrong result from the [/2.2/privileges](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/privileges) API.

Documentation related privilege details are listing for all the Stack Exchange sites, but is should be list only for Stack Overflow.

There is a bug already reported about the Documentation privilege in the [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/7292/) site. Fixing on the API details, will solve this issue.