# Documentation-related privileges are still searchable in the help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center, documentation

*Related: ["Secret" Documentation Privileges on sites other than SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297111/secret-documentation-privileges-on-sites-other-than-so)*

---

When searching something in the help center (e.g. "comment"), documentation-related privileges are still shown in the help center. By searching ["documentation"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=documentation), looks like there are 3 privileges which are still searchable:

- documentation comments
- documentation votes
- documentation review

and clicking them return to the privilege list.

However, considering that [SO Documentation has been sunset](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation), shouldn't they be removed altogether from the help center? This applies to **all** sites, [not just Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=documentation); for instance, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed them from MSE, which should (soon) propagate throughout the rest of the network.

I don't *see* any per-site overrides (per-site copies of pages which don't get overwritten by changes to the copy on MSE), which makes sense since Documentation was only piloted on Stack Overflow, but please let me know if you spot one.